# MacOS: conditional CommandGroup

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a custom `CommandGroup` (`customPasteboardCommands` - it replaces the built-in `.pasteboard` group) which I would like to render conditionally.

What is the correct syntax?

I tried two ways, none of them worked:

**First**

```
if viewModel.shouldUseCustomCommandGroup {
    customPasteboardCommands
}
```

Error:

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result
> builder 'CommandsBuilder'

**Second:**

```
viewModel.shouldUseCustomCommandGroup ? customPasteboardCommands : EmptyCommands()
```

Error:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'some
> Commands' and 'EmptyCommands'

**Full code:**

App.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct macos_playgroundApp: App {
    private let viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Button("Toggle custom CommandGroup") {
                viewModel.onToggleCustomCommandGroup()
            }
        }
        .commands {
            commands
        }
    }

    @CommandsBuilder
    var commands: some Commands {
        emptyNewItemCommands
        viewModel.shouldUseCustomCommandGroup ? customPasteboardCommands : EmptyCommands()
    }

    var emptyNewItemCommands: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) {}
    }

    var customPasteboardCommands: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .pasteboard) {
            Button("Select All") {
                print("Custom select all activated")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("a", modifiers: [.command])
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.swift

```
import Foundation

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldUseCustomCommandGroup: Bool = false

    func onToggleCustomCommandGroup() {
        shouldUseCustomCommandGroup = !shouldUseCustomCommandGroup
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more Mac standard to always show the command and enable/disable it as needed. So you could use disabled on the button, `.disabled(! viewModel.shouldUseCustomCommandGroup)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190831/swiftui-conditional-commands-on-the-scene/71199457#71199457

Comment: @ChrisR Your code adds a new menu. I would like a command group that replaces an existing one (.pasteboard) based on some condition. I showed it in the code, and now I also updated the description to point it out.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, that is a good point about following Mac standard. As for the code, do you know a way to reuse the built-in command button, and only conditionally replace it with the custom button? Or do I need to reimplement the built-in behavior e.g. for "Select All"? I posted [a new SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459794/macos-customize-an-existing-menu-command) about the higher level behavior I am aiming for.

Comment: have a look at this SO post/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660715/enabling-and-disabling-commandgroup-menu-items/70660967#70660967